# Login with Google using django-alluath doesn't work correctly

Tags: django, google-signin, django-allauth

I've implemented Google authorization using `django-allauth`, but it only works for users signed up with `django-allauth` and for users signed up with `django` the authorization doesn't work and redirects to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/signup/ with the message "Sign Up. You are about to use your Google account to login to localhost. As a final step, please complete the following form:".

[image]

How can I allow users not registered with `django-allauth` to sign in with Google?

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'smart_selects',
    'users',
    'main_app',
    'chat',
    'channels',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'django_filters',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

SITE_ID = 4

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.AdvUser'
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('users:login')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "main_app:home"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "main_app:home"

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

`models.py`

```
class AdvUser(AbstractUser):

    first_name = models.CharField("Ім'я", blank=False, null=False, default='', max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField("Прізвище", blank=False, null=False, default='', max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField("Нік", blank=False, null=False, max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=150, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Аватар', upload_to=get_upload_path, blank=True,
                               default='default/users/default_avatar.png')
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name='Номер телефону', unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    last_online = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Кінець останнього сеансу', blank=True, null=True)
    online = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Статус - Online/Offline', default=0)
    active_chat = models.ForeignKey(Thread, verbose_name='Активний чат', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    null=True, blank=True)
    notification = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Повідомлення', default=False)
    count_ads = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Кількість доданих оголошень', default=0)
```

Comment: please share related settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this problem was solved by a great person and after many hours of googling, I found this link with the answer to my question: https://devpress.csdn.net/python/6304c490c67703293080de34.html

`Note`: I changed `is_authenticated()` to `is_authenticated` in `adapter.get_login_redirect_url` and use `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` without `.format()`, but it depends on your settings.